# Datatypes all display as UNKNOWN in Oracle SQL developer models

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqldatatypes

[image: Unknown values]

When setting up the tables, I can select data types perfectly fine. I'm new to oracle sql development, and just installed the server + developer tools, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

How would I fix this?

Edit: Example in editor: [image: Data types visible]

Comment: Likely unrelated to your issue, but you should better avoid creating objects under SYSTEM user; create a new user and use it instead.

Comment: How exactly are you creating your data model - by hand, or by reverse engineering an existing system?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, Hand, I'm just getting used to the environment, as Aleksej pointed out, I have not even created a new user. So, all of my settings are basically vanilla fresh from installation, not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I create the tables, then open up a data dictionary through data modeller, selecting my system schema, and the above unknown values appear in the ERD.

Comment: @Arvayne so you used the import - data dictionary feature? The data types should have come over. The SYSTEM schema is making me curious, but that should not matter. if you open the table in SQL Developer, and then click on the model tab - do the data types show there?

Comment: I used to see this issue all the time when I used custom Domains in my models. They don't get saved along with the data model, so when you move to another computer or upgrade SQL Developer they'd all get lost. I soon learned to just use ordinary Oracle datatypes everywhere.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp yeah but i doubt a brand new user is using domains...unless they just opened a design someone else gave them - but that's why i asked how they built the model

Answer (score 0):

@Arvayne
if you choose "Data Type"= Logical, you will be able to choose from several options as "Source Type".

So e.g. if you choose from the "Source Type" drop down menu the value "Numeric", datatype will display as "Number".

Hope this will help.
cheers.